# Adding GeoJSON properties when creating marker in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, export, markers

I used a manual marker input development under Leaflet found on this website : http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/basic/addmarker.html

I have added two properties to the markers: name and description and the possibility to register these markers.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Saisie waypoints</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/togeojson@0.16.0"></script>

<style>
#map {
height: 700px;
width: 1500px

}

#delete, #export {
            position: absolute;
            top:150px;
            left:10px;
            z-index:1000;
            background:white;
            color:black;
            padding:6px;
            border-radius:4px;
            font-family: 'Arial';
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size:12px;
            text-decoration:none;
    
        }
        #export {
            top:200px;
        }
 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="a">Lat</a>
<input type="text" id="b">Long</a>
<input type="text" id="c">Name</a>
<input type="text" id="d">Description</a>
<button type="button" onclick="clickme()">Create</button>

<div id="map" </div>

<a href="#" id='delete' data-toggle="tooltip">Delete</a>
<a href="#" id='export' data-toggle="tooltip">Export Geojson</a>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([30, -8], 9);  

    var osm=new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
    
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

function clickme(){


    var lat =   document.getElementById("a").value;
    var lng =   document.getElementById("b").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("c").value;
    var description = document.getElementById("d").value;
    
        
    L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(drawnItems).bindPopup("Name: " + name + "</br>" + "Description: " + description + "</br>" + "latitude: " + lat + "</br>" + "longitude: " + lng);

    map.setView([lat,lng], 9); 
    
    
 }
 
  document.getElementById('delete').onclick = function (e) {
      drawnItems.clearLayers();
    }


document.getElementById('export').onclick = function (e) {
      // Extractions GeoJson from featureGroup
      var geojson = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
      // Stringify the GeoJson
     
      var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(geojson));
      // Create export
      document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData);
      document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download', 'data.geojson');
    }
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to export in geojson format these markers with their names and descriptions. In the current export I only have the latitude and longitude coordinates of the registered markers.

What changes do I need to make in order to get these complete registrations?

Answer (score 4):

If you create GeoJSON layer in Leaflet from GeoJSON file/object, you'll see that each Leaflet feature object gets `feature` property, which contains source GeoJSON object with all it's properties. If you create GeoJSON object from such layer with `.toGeoJSON()` method, you get initial GeoJSON object, again with all it's properties.

Taking this into account when creating your marker, you can add property `feature` to Leaflet marker object and add desired properties to it. These properties will then be used when creating GeoJSON object with the `.toGeoJSON()` method.

In your case this could look something like this:

```
function clickme(){

  var lat =   document.getElementById("a").value;
  var lng =   document.getElementById("b").value;
  var name = document.getElementById("c").value;
  var description = document.getElementById("d").value;  
      
  var marker = L.marker([lat, lng]).bindPopup("Name: " + name + "</br>" + "Description: " + description + "</br>" + "latitude: " + lat + "</br>" + "longitude: " + lng);;
  marker.feature = {};
  marker.feature.type = 'Feature';    // Correction, thanks to @Manard82
  marker.feature.properties = {};
  marker.feature.properties.name = name;
  marker.feature.properties.decription = description;
  marker.addTo(drawnItems);

  map.setView([lat,lng], 9); 
   
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the generated geojson file, I noticed that it did not open, the name and description being under geometry. I applied the following modification:

```
  var lat =   document.getElementById("a").value;
  var lng =   document.getElementById("b").value;
  var name = document.getElementById("c").value;
  var description = document.getElementById("d").value;  
      
  var marker = L.marker([lat, lng]).bindPopup("Nom: " + name + "</br>" + "Description: " + description + "</br>" + "Latitude: " + lat + "</br>" + "Longitude: " + lng + "</br>" +"<input type='button' value='Effacer ce waypoint' class='marker-delete-button'/>");

  marker.on("popupopen", onPopupOpen);
       
   
 feature = marker.feature = marker.feature || {}; // Initialize feature
 feature.type = feature.type || "Feature"; // Initialize feature.type
 var props = feature.properties = feature.properties || {}; // Initialize feature.properties
 marker.feature.properties.name = name;
 marker.feature.properties.description = description;
    
    
    
      marker.addTo(drawnItems);

  map.setView([lat,lng], 9); 
   
 }
```

Comment: You are right, I completely overlooked that. My answer is corrected now accordingly.