# Conversion of coordinates into degrees, minutes and seconds to decimal degrees

Tags: convert, latitude-longitude, degrees-minutes-seconds

Within the framework of manual marker input ([Adding GeoJSON properties when creating marker in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383363/adding-geojson-properties-when-creating-marker-in-leaflet)), I would like to propose the conversion of coordinates in degrees, minutes, and seconds to decimal degrees.

I looked for the way that seemed simplest to me, taking inspiration from developments.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Convert DMS to Decimal Degrees </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div>
 <form id="dm2decimal" name="dm2decimal" >
            <label for="degrees1">Convert DMS -> Decimal degrees | Degrees: <input type="text" id="degrees1" name="degrees1" size="3" maxlength="3" /></label>
            <label for="minutes1">Minutes: <input type="text" id="minutes1" name="minutes1" size="2" maxlength="2" /></label>
            <label for="secondes1">Seconds: <input type="text" id="seconds1" name="seconds1" size="10" maxlength="10" /></label>
                        <select id="direction" name="direction">
                <option value="N">N</option>
                <option value="S">S</option>
                <option value="E">E</option>
                <option value="W">W</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" onclick="convert()" value="Convert">
            <!--<button type="button" onclick="convert()">Convert</button>-->   
        
</form>

Latitude: <textarea id="latdm" name="latdm" oninput="validateNumber(this)" rows="1" size="10" maxlength="10"></textarea>
Longitude: <textarea id="lngdm" name="lngdm" oninput="validateNumber(this)" rows="1" size="10" maxlength="10"></textarea>
Name: <input type="text" id="name" title="Name"></a>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#dm2decimal').validate({
                    rules: {
                        degrees1: {
                            required: true,
                            digits: true,
                            range: [0, 180]
                        },
                        minutes1: {
                            required: true,
                            number: true,
                            range: [0, 59]
                        },
                        
                        seconds1: {
                            required: true,
                            number: true,
                            range: [0, 59.9999999]
                        },
                        
                        
                    } //rules
                }); //validate
            }); //ready
            
// Forcer le séparateur point et refuser la virgule 

var validNumber = new RegExp(/^-?\d*\.?\d*$/);
var lastValid = document.getElementById("latdm").value;
function validateNumber(elem) {
  if (validNumber.test(elem.value)) {
    lastValid = elem.value;
  } else {
    elem.value = lastValid;
  }
}   
            
function convert()
    {
        var d1 = document.getElementById("degrees1").value;
        var m1 = document.getElementById("minutes1").value;
        var s1 = document.getElementById("seconds1").value;
        var cap = document.getElementById("direction").value;
        
       var dd = d1 + m1/60 + s1/3600;

    if (cap == "S" || cap == "W") {
        dd = dd * -1;
    } // Don't do anything for N or E
    return dd;
        
    if (cap == "N" || cap == "S")   
    document.getElementById("latdm").innerHTML = dd;

    if (cap == "E" || cap == "W")
    document.getElementById("lngdm").innerHTML = dd;    
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Once the degrees, minutes, and seconds are entered when I start the conversion, the latitude and longitude fields are not filled in. I don't see any error in the Chrome console.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 issues with the posted code:

1. The code returns before setting the result in the appropriate form element.  Move `return dd;` to the end of the function.
2. The values returned by the `<input>` elements will be strings, so you will get unexpected results from this:

   ```
   var dd = d1 + m1/60 + s1/3600;
   ```

   like `420.233333333333333340.0033333333333333335`. Convert the inputs to numbers (with `parseFloat` or `parseInt`) before processing them.

Updated `convert` function:

```
function convert()
    {
        var d1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("degrees1").value);
        var m1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("minutes1").value);
        var s1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("seconds1").value);
        var cap = document.getElementById("direction").value;
        
       var dd = d1 + m1/60 + s1/3600;

    if (cap == "S" || cap == "W") {
        dd = parseFloat(dd) * -1;
    } // Don't do anything for N or E
        
    if (cap == "N" || cap == "S")   
    document.getElementById("latdm").innerHTML = dd;

    if (cap == "E" || cap == "W")
    document.getElementById("lngdm").innerHTML = dd;
    return dd;
    }
```