# Choose the export name of a file from Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, export

Is it possible to choose a name for the file exported to GeoJSON from Leaflet?

In this discussion : [Adding GeoJSON properties when creating marker in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383363/adding-geojson-properties-when-creating-marker-in-leaflet) , there is the possibility to export to a file in geojson format, the file name is set to "data.geojson".

```
document.getElementById('export').onclick = function (e) {
      // Extractions GeoJson from featureGroup
      var geojson = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
      // Stringify the GeoJson
     
      var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(geojson));
      // Create export
      document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData);
      document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download', 'data.geojson');
    }
```

Would it be possible to create a dialog box to fill in another name?

Edit

I have just found a solution with an "input"

```
Filename: <input type="text" id="file" size="20"></a>


document.getElementById('export').onclick = function (e) {       
      // Extractions GeoJson from featureGroup
      var geojson = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
      // Stringify the GeoJson
      var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(geojson));
      // Create export
      var filename = document.getElementById("file").value;
      document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData);
      document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download', filename + '.geojson');
        
       }
```

Comment: This is is not a GIS or GIS software related question, but pure HTML/JS one, and as such more suited for StackOverflow site.

Comment: Please do not place Answers in the body of your Question. Doing so breaks our Question/Answer model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use every name you want.
You can open a Dialog from click or you can use the built-in `pompt()` function.

```
document.getElementById('export').onclick = function (e) {
      // Extractions GeoJson from featureGroup
      var geojson = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
      // Stringify the GeoJson

      var name = prompt('Enter file name','data.geojson'); // second param can be empty, it is the default value
     
      var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(geojson));
      // Create export
      document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData);
      document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download', name);
    }
```